Why can I call the same .msi twice / multiple times on Windows Server operating system?
my question straight forward: I'm building a Windows installer with WixSharp. Using a template project for example, I can't install the same software twice. Windows will give me an error that an instance is already installed on my local machine.
However on my virtual machine (Windows Server 2019) I can execute the .msi file twice, but on the second try the Wizard won't open but the installation will still start from scratch.
Did anybody else encounter the same problem? And so how can I work around it? It's very weird.
Thanks for your time
